# Скриншот с веб-камеры

Tags: python, python-3.x, камера, screenshots

Как сделать скришнот с веб-камеры используя `OpenCV(python3)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import cv2

# Включаем первую камеру
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# "Прогреваем" камеру, чтобы снимок не был тёмным
for i in range(30):
    cap.read()

# Делаем снимок    
ret, frame = cap.read()

# Записываем в файл
cv2.imwrite('cam.png', frame)   

# Отключаем камеру
cap.release()
```